# Japanese characters display as blocks/squares in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, language

I've been having a problem trying to display Japanese characters on my Windows 8 system. I've installed the required language pack but that doesn't seem to solve it.

Characters display fine on web browsers, however everywhere else they just display as squares.

Even the language selection in the control panel can't display them (and they should work there, right?)

[image]

The only other solution I've found on the internet is to change the system locale, which I would really like to avoid since it can have a lot of unwanted side effects.

Answer (score 0):

Appearing as squares suggests a font issue.

Try deleting the file C:\Windows\system32\FNTCACHE.DAT and restart.  This is the font cache and resolved a similar issue I had on Windows 7 when Japanese & Chinese characters were displaying for menu & titles but not for controls within dialogues.